# Shadow on text and on box have not the same Y position

Tags: html, css, shadow, box-shadow

I'm using a function for generating a gradian shadow on text or html tag.
And I don't understand why the angle of the shadow isn't the same.

To get the same result on HTML tag I have to divide by 2 the y position of shadow (you have to uncomment this 3 lines on SCSS (l.14-l.16) on the [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgadyP) to see the result)

```
   // @if($i) {
   //   $y: $i/2;
   // }
```

**Look like**

*Line commented*
[image: First]

*Line not commented*
[image]

Comment: I think that is because you rotated you right div and that he is calculating from your rotated position.

Comment: Agree with Vinc, it is due to the rotation you are giving to the element.

Comment: You right it's only that :/ I have to handle that on the function ...

Comment: @Arthur I have a small question. Are you using a libary for the css because I have never seen css like that.

Comment: It's SCSS, very usefull : http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a answer to close this question with @Vinc199789 comment:

"I think that is because you rotated you right div and that he is calculating from your rotated position."